# ChildBrowser.java syntax error

Tags: java, android, cordova, childbrowser

In ChildBrowser.java (2.0.0) 
line: 356
Cordava: 2.9.0

is syntax error:

The method setPluginsEnabled(boolean) is undefined for the type WebSetting

```
                // WebView
       webview = new WebView(ctx.getActivity());
       webview.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
       webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
       WebViewClient client = new ChildBrowserClient(edittext);
       webview.setWebViewClient(client);
       WebSettings settings = webview.getSettings();
       settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
       settings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
       settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);


       settings.setPluginsEnabled(true);


       settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
       webview.loadUrl(url);
       webview.setId(6);
       webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
       webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
       webview.requestFocus();
       webview.requestFocusFromTouch();
```

And I don't know how to remove it.

Thank you for help.

TB

Comment: There is no `setPlugingsEnabled` method in this class: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html

Comment: Ok, it is possible. But This error is in ChildBrowser.java on the line (356) where is: settings.setPluginsEnabled(true);  and Eclipse says: The method setPluginsEnabled(boolean) is undefined for the type WebSetting. And I don't know how to get rid of this error.

Comment: Remove the entire line. The method you are trying to call does not exist. Read the API for the class that I linked to above and you will see all methods that do exist. Call one of those instead.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg: it does not exist *anymore*. Starting Android 4.3 the method in question has been removed from the public API and been replaced with `setPluginState(...)`. See answer below for more details. In any case, since also the replacement is deprecated, developers should no longer rely on its functionality, so the correct course of action is to migrate away from using any `setPlugin*()` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method you're looking for has been deprecated and removed from the public API with the introduction of Android 4.3 (API level 18):

```
/**
 * Sets whether the WebView should enable plugins. The default is false.
 *
 * @param flag true if plugins should be enabled
 * @deprecated This method has been deprecated in favor of
 *             {@link #setPluginState}
 * @hide Since API level {@link android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES#JELLY_BEAN_MR2}
 */
@Deprecated
public synchronized void setPluginsEnabled(boolean flag) {
    throw new MustOverrideException();
}
```

[Link to source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.3_r2.1/android/webkit/WebSettings.java#1023).

As pointed out in the Javadoc above, starting API level 18, you can use the following method in stead, and pass in `PluginState.ON`.

```
setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState state)
```

Do note that this method has also been deprecated saying that *"Plugins will not be supported in future, and should not be used."*. [Link.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setPluginState%28android.webkit.WebSettings.PluginState%29)

Here's the actual [API 18 diff report for `WebSettings`](http://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/18/changes/android.webkit.WebSettings.html), giving a handy overview of all changes to the class.

Comment: And do you know what to use instead ChildBrowser plugin? THX

Comment: @TomášBalíček: I imagine you're going to have to wait for an update for the plugin, or make the change yourself and submit a pull request to the main repo. However, for the time being you can probably avoid the compile error by building against Android 4.2.2 (API level 17) - assuming your code is not using any 4.3 specific features.